# iterate files in sub-folder

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, directory

I have a folder-structure as follows:

```
c:/
  myDir/
    matchingDirName/
      myFile1.ext
    notMatchingDirName/
      myFile2.ext
  anotherDir/
    matchingDirName/
      myFile3.ext
```

What I want is to get all the files with the given extension `ext` that are located in the subfolder `matchingDirName` within any parent directory.

So I need some kind of pattern for a file as follows: `<folder>/matchingDirName/*.ext`.

I allready tried this which gives me **file not found**:

```
cd c:
for /f %%i in ('dir /a-h-s /b "*/matchingDirName/*.ext"') do echo %%i
```

Is there a way to get only those files that are located in a given folder?

In my example both `myFile1.ext` and `myFile3.ext` should be returned.

Comment: If you know what folder you need to get to, why don't you do a change directory all the way down to that sub folder?

Comment: @Squashman Because I don´t know its parent-folder and thus can´t call change directory, I´ve updated the question accordingly. So I need to get those `ext`-files within a folder named `<anyDir>/matchingDirName/*.ext`.

Comment: This is partially part of the problem but does not solve the whole problem.  Doing a `cd c:` does not change the working directory to c:\.  You either specify `C:` or `CD /D C:\\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
dir /s /b /a-d c:\*.ext | findstr /r /c:"\\matchingDirName\\[^\\]*$"
```

Searchs all the `ext` files and filter the list using a regular expression to print only those files that are stored inside the matching directory name

Now, to iterate over the list inside a batch file

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    dir /s /b /a-d c:\*.ext ^| findstr /r /c:"\\matchingDirName\\[^\\]*$"
') do (
    echo File found : "%%a"
)
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere, 1) answer updated 2) No, no absolute path. It only checks the name of the parent folder of the `.ext` file.

Comment: Wow, works perfectly. I missed the `^` to escape the pipe-character in front of `findstr`. Thanks for your help

Comment: I suggest to add the `/I` switch to `findstr` in order to treat directory names case-insensitively, like Windows itself does as well...

Answer (score 1):

In case the directory hierarchy depth is exactly as you showed in your sample, the following works:

```dos
@echo off
for /D %%A in ("C:\*.*") do (
    for /D %%B in ("%%~fA\*.*") do (
        if /I "%%~nxB"=="matchingDirName" (
            for %%C in ("%%~fB\*.ext") do (
                echo "%%~fC"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The first two nested `for /D` loops enumerate the directories (`/D`) of the first and second directory hierarchy level. The `if /I` query checks the pure second-level directory name (`%%~nxB`) against the predefined name in a case-insensitive manner (`/I`). The inner-most `for` loop iterates through all the `*.ext` files in the matching directories finally.

---

For an arbitrary directory hierarchy depth, use the following:

```dos
@echo off
for /R "C:\" %%A in ("*.ext") do (
    for %%B in ("%%~dpA.") do (
        if /I "%%~nxB"=="matchingDirName" (
            echo "%%~fA"
        )
    )
)
```

The outer `for /R` loop enumerates all `*.ext` files in the entire directory hierarchy recursively (`/R`). The inner `for` loop recieves the parent directory of each `*.ext` file (`%%~dpA.`), so it iterates once only per file; for instance, the current file is `C:\myDir\matchingDirName\myFile1.ext`, so `%%~dpA.` expands to `C:\myDir\matchingDirName\.`, which is equivalent to `C:\myDir\matchingDirName`; the purpose of this loop is to extract the pure directory name (`%%~nxB`; for example, `matchingDirName`). The `if /I` query checks that directory name against the predefined name in a case-insensitive manner (`/I`) finally.

Comment: Shouldn´t it be `if /I "%%~nB"=="matchingDirName"`? You´re comparing dir-names that don´t have an extension.

Comment: Depends on whether you want to regard or dismiss extensions in the directory name; supposing your `matchingDirName` is actually `Matching` and a directory `Matching.dir` is found, the `.dir` part is ignored when using the `~n` modifier...

Comment: And the `~nx`-modifier will handle this? Didn´t know this. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: `~nx` extracts the full name of an item, `~x` extracts the last `.` and everything after, and `~n` extracts everything before the last `.`; in case there is no `.` at all, `~x` is empty and both `~n` and `~nx` expand to the full name...

Comment: I´m still unsure what you´re looping on `for %%B in ("%%~dpA.")` as the previous loop already iterates all ext-files within `C:/`, doesn´t it?

Comment: Yes, that is true; `for %%B` iterates once only per each item and is intended to extract the pure name of the immediate parent directory: `%%~dpA` is the full path to the parent of the iterated `*.ext` file item, including a trailing backslash; the appended `.` simply defines "this directory"; supposing the current item is `C:\myDir\matchingDirName\myFile1.ext`, `%%~dpA.` is `C:\myDir\matchingDirName\.`, which is the same as `C:\myDir\matchingDirName`; the `for %%B` loop iterates through this, and since `~nx` is used in `%%~nxB`, the pure directory name is returned, which is `matchingDirName`;

Comment: Thank fou for your explanation, I got it now.